# How to Escape a Query Parameter

Tags: php, plugin-elementapi

Extremely not a PHP developer here but trying to set up a simple API with Element API. I've got the basics working to filter my entry results based off of a `query` URL parameter:

```
use craft\elements\Entry;

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'recipes.json' => function() {
            $entryCriteria = [
                'section' => 'recipes'
            ];

            // filter by search query
            $searchQuery = Craft::$app->request->getQueryParam('query');
            if($searchQuery) {
                $entryCriteria += [
                    'search' => $searchQuery,
                    'orderBy' => 'score'
                ];
            }

            return [
                'elementType' => Entry::class,
                'elementsPerPage' => 12,
                'criteria' => $entryCriteria,
                'transformer' => function(Entry $entry) {
                    return [
                        'id' => $entry->id,
                        'title' => $entry->title,
                        'uri' => $entry->uri,
                        'recipeImg' => $entry->recipeImg->one()->url
                    ];
                },
                'pretty' => true
            ];
        }
    ]
];
```

I'm guessing `getQueryParam()` doesn't escape the returned data by default, and I would assume it's a good idea to do so before passing it into the plugin, but I don't know how to do that. I assume Craft has a built-in function for that but I don't know what it is or how to use it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to escape the parameter, that's done by the element query for you. Passing the parameter directly will allow your users to use [search syntax](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/searching.html) in the search term, but won't present a security issue.

Comment: Worth noting that the search syntax _can_ allow users to filter by information that is otherwise not public—for example, if a site allowed accountholders to publish (and search by) biographical information… `email:"august domain com"` might make it easier to surmise login info; or `localChapterZipCode:123*` could expose users’ general geographic location. Of course, this is a pretty limited attack surface, as the user would have to know what your fields’ and attributes’ handles are, understand keyword normalization, scoring, etc.

Comment: @AugustMiller Good point! Any best practice to preventing this leak? I.e. is there a way to disallow search syntax when passing user terms?